# include path and invalid escape character in VS code

Tags: visual-studio-code, escaping, character

The red underlined text at line 7 in the image below is detected as having an error **invalid escape character in string**.

This string is a folder path. Why invalid, and how should I do?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to @Andy Lin, my issue was resolved by changing the forward-slash "/" with a backslash "\": now the executable path is set in VS code.

I was facing the same issue: I downloaded PHP package but couldn't locate "php.exe", which is the main requirement in setting up the executable path in VS code.

### Solution:

First, you have to copy the location where PHP downloaded package is located and copy its path, for example in my case it is `"C:\Program Files\php-7.4.5"`

Set `Path` by going into properties of `This Pc` > `Advance System Setting` > `Advance` > `Environment Variable`

A window will pop up and there will be two types of variable:
- User Variable
- System Variable

Edit the path and add this PHP package location in both variables and check it in CMD: it works.

Now open VS code goto `Preference` > `Setting`: there will be an error indication:

> No executable file of PHP is found

Copy that PHP package location and add simply `"\php.exe"` in it and change backslash to forward-slash.

Now your address should look like this: `"C:/Program Files/php-7.4.5/php.exe"`.

Paste it in VS Code Setting.

> "php.validate.executablePath": "C:/Program Files/php-7.4.5/php.exe"

Finally, restart VS Code: it should work.

Answer (score 6):

It has to be backslash "/" instead of slash "\", however, I have no idea why is backslash.

win10, my os, uses slash for path and vscode uses backslash....

Comment: You mean forward slash : "/"

A backslash is "\"

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me!

```
C:/Users/dell/.virtualenvs/Scripts/python
```